# Running R in SPSS Modeller V17 - Version issues

Tags: r, spss, spss-modeler

I have SPSS V17 and want to run `dplyr` package in the r transform node. I am getting the following error

> Error: This is R 3.1.0, package 'dplyr' needs >= 3.1.2"

Do I have to load the `dplyr 3.1.0` only package or is there another solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a dplyr package version that is compatible with your current R version, which is 3.1.0 according to your error message. Example the dplyr 0.1 was the latest release of the package before R 3.1.0 was released so you can install that by downloading the tar.gz file from the [dplyr cran archives](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/), and installing that using the install.package function.

Comment: Thankyou, I will give that a go

Comment: To load a package from cran archives that will work for a particular R version, is it the rule of thumb to compare the date of the R version (eg R3.1.0 was released April, 2014) and load the latest R package version before that date ? For example dplyr_0.1.3.tar.gz was released 15-Mar-2014. And if that is the case, do I have to go to every package I want and look for each version from the archive before I download it ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Since the cran page gets updated with the info on new versions, you can't see the exact R version the old versions depend on but you can infer correctly from the release dates. Secondly, you don't have to look for the archived versions for each package unless you face the same dependency issue with another package. In my experience, most new package version releases are backwards compatible to the old R versions.

Comment: Thanks again, that helped alot

Comment: Hi there again, new to all this, how do I mark the question as answered ?

Comment: @MP61 To do this, you click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer". Thanks.